# How to make permanent block in Network Request Blocking

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make webpages load faster because I want to buy a GPU, and I need the sites to permanently load faster, so I need to block scripts urls permanently.

How can I do it?

Having dev-tools open all the time will not work, because i open a link when it has stock and i dont have time to block it, must be blocked all the time.

Comment: I also need the answer.